# Are there any flags for autopep8 (vscode), to allow multiple import in the same line?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autopep8

I know that you can pass `"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--max-line-length=200"]` in `.vscode/settings.json` to override the max 79 length for a line, are there any flags for allow multiple line imports.
What I want:

```
import json, os, h5py, pyperclip
```

this is just an example, usually I'd group modules with similar function in the code. Its more of a preference thing ;).

Edit: I could always do something like

```
# fmt: off
import json, os, h5py, pyperclip
# fmt: on
```

but I want a solution that is just pure vs-code settings based, like for the `max-line-length` I explained above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--ignore", "E401"],
```

And this is the [official docs](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/), you can find how to configure it with the suitable configurations.

Comment: comming back to this, where do you get these `Exxx` codes? I tried finding them but couldnt. using `;` in a line separates two lines in a single line, `print(1) ; print(2)`, but autopep8 automatically converts that into a new line, how do I ingnore this?

Comment: I'm so sorry, guess I didnt read properly. I got them. Thanks again